# Is there an event when whole template is rendered in Vue3?

Tags: recursion, events, components, vuejs3

I have some recursion in the component template and I need add some functionality to the result html. So I need to wait till the whole html of the component and its nested components are available. What is the right time to add this functionality? Functionality means call jQuery plugin on the result html.

The code looks like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li  v-for="category in categories"
                 :key="category.id"
                 id="menuItem_{{category.id}}"
                 data-module="{{category.module?.id ? category.module?.id : 0}}"
            >
                <div>
                    {{category.name}}
                </div>

                <CategoriesList v-if="category.all_children?.length" :categories="category.all_children" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation for my previous project. I was using angular and NxJS and I used observables for doing this.

You can create a dynamic array of observables, init it in the main component, add a subscription and then update them when each component is rendered (in the mounted function for example). When all your array is done, you can then call the function / apply your functionality.

Seems like something like exists in Vuejs: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/04/02/vuejs-rxjs-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject
or https://www.thisdot.co/blog/introduction-to-vuejs-and-rxjs

I could check out the code tonight and send it to you if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks but simple answer is mounter hook. Thats all.